# different hibernate session factories on different machines for accessing single db instance

Tags: java, database, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have different hibernate session factories on different machines for accessing single db instance and it is creating havoc(gives stale data/throws Nullpointer Exception) between sessions. Is there any way to solve this or I can have only one hibernate session factory for one database instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking inside Finally got solution, The Culprit was storage engine InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are a few types of handle this havoc.

- only use short-life sessions.
- or use version-fields in tables and catch entity-not-sync-with-db-Exceptions
- or try to sync the entity-managers
- or use enver
- or use audition
- or use the read/write lock of database-rows

Some more may exists